# ROR application - in js.coffee can't access gon variable set in controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Will out line in broad detail the problem followed by actual code.  Specifically in some javscript I am unable to accss a Gon variable I have set.
I have some javascript to monitor if user changes a p-value.  If so we do some js.coffee processing, follwed by call to controller, followed by some more js.coffee.

The variable I am having trouble with (believe I have set but error screen says otherwise) is gon.actual_oil_p50.

Overall processing is  js.coffee -> controller -> (more) js.coffee

drills.js.coffee ( get_changed_p_values ) -> drills.controller (                       p_value_selected )  -> drills.js.coffee ( displayAssumptions )

In the controller I set the variable gon.actual_oil_p50 which I then can't access in js.coffee displayAssumptions

(coffee.js) get_changes-p_values - called when p-value changes

```
get_changed_p_values = (drill_id)-> 
data = $('#x_evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()
$.ajax
   url:"/drills/#{drill_id}/p_value_selected.json",
   type:"post"
   dataType: 'json'   # data type of response
   data: data
   success: (data,success,xhr)->
     displayAssumptions data
     calculateResult drill_id
   failure: (data,success,xhr)->
     ...
```

(drills_controller)

```
  def p_value_selected
    index = params[:name][:id].to_i
    # if current discovery target is a user valuation exit - p10 etc not applicable
    if @selections[index]["user_valuation"]
      render :nothing => true
    else
      p_value =  params[:pvalue].to_s
      load_stake    
      @assum = EvaluationAssumption.new
      @assum.probability_of_success = @stake.company_specified_drill_risk

      # PMLC - set gon variable which I can't seem to access
      # in following js.coffee
      gon.actual_oil_p50 = @selections[index]["oil_p50"]
      # PMLC

      case p_value
        when "p90"
          @assum.resource_estimation_oil = @selections[index]["oil_p90"]
          @assum.resource_estimation_gas = @selections[index]["gas_p90"]
        when "p50"
         ....
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @assum }
      end
    end
  end
```

(coffee.js) displayAssumptions

```
# (02) display the selected assumption params
displayAssumptions = (data)-> 
    $('#evaluation_assumption_resource_estimation_oil').val(data.resource_estimation_oil)
    $('#evaluation_assumption_in_ground_value_oil').val(data.in_ground_value_oil)
    $('#evaluation_assumption_resource_estimation_gas').val(data.resource_estimation_gas)
    $('#evaluation_assumption_in_ground_value_gas').val(data.in_ground_value_gas)
        $('#evaluation_assumption_probability_of_success').val(data.probability_of_success)

    # PMLC
    # now cater for when p-value selected was not p10, p50, p90, or fill to spill
    pvalue_slider = document.getElementById("pvalue").value

    if pvalue_slider.indexOf("%") > -1 
      # PMLC - this value should be set from controller
      #     but error message show otherwise
      gon.actual_oil_p50 = gon.watch.actual_oil_p50

      percChanceOil = parseInt(pvalue_slider.split "%", 1) / 100
      amt_oil = jStat.lognormal.inv((1-percChanceOil),gon.mean,gon.stdDev)
      # then shift right or left depending on mean value p50) for this oil00
      amt_oil = amt_oil * (( gon.actual_oil_p50 / gon.std_oil_p50) )

      $('#evaluation_assumption_resource_estimation_oil').val(amt_oil)
```

Note in view/layouts/application.html.erb I have

```
<head>    
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Drill Investor" %></title>
    <%= include_gon(watch:true) %> 
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Resultant error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'actual_oil_p50' of undefined

viewing the page source I get 
window.gon={};gon.mean=6.21664219934878;gon.stdDev=0.499350777509958;gon.std_oil_p50=500;
that is gon.actual_oil_p50 is not set

However in the controller I have put message after setting the gon.actual_p50_value e.g.after the statement in controller

```
gon.actual_oil_p50 = @selections[index]["oil_p50"]
puts "did I set gon.actual_oil_p50+ + gon.actual_oil_p50
```

it tells me it has been set appropriatly

many thanks in advance fpr any hints/answers - Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's either rendering JSON, which doesn't have the GON definition in it, or nothing.

I'm not sure how that setting would propagate back to an HTML page.

Comment: to conform you are referring to respond_to do |format| format.json { render :json => @assum } end in the controller ?

Comment: Right. That's suggesting the controller only emits JSON. You can always have a `.json.erb` file or a `.json.jbuilder` to handle that sort of thing rather than having to resort to that sort of method. If you have this data available in JSON format, that also largely eliminates the need for bridging via the `gon` mechanism.

Comment: I have just marked this question as answered.  How else could I get the actual_p50_amt_oil to the js.coffee OR execute "amt_oil = jStat.lognormal.inv((1-percChanceOil),gon.mean,gon.stdDev)" in the controller.  Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you just grab the JSON data that contains those values with jQuery and use them on your page as you would any other data? You might have to do that asynchronously, but that's usually not too much of a struggle.

Comment: Usually something like [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is a good place to start.